# Clear console using OS Module yields unknown character and does not work

Tags: python, pycharm

For a programming class, I'm creating a console based choose your own adventure game. My goal is to implement a function that clears the console, so I do not have to keep creating space to make things look organized. However, when using the OS module to clear the console like below,

```
import os

def clear_console():
command = 'clear'
if os.name in ('nt', 'dos'):
    command = 'cls'
os.system(command)

clear_console()
```

the console is not cleared and a strange character shows up in its place, resembling a rectangle with a diagonal, that when copied and pasted, creates nothing. I have no clue what's going wrong here.
For reference, I am using Pycharm, which I theorize may impact the display of this character.

Comment: PS: you may use directly: https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html or other libraries (e.g. https://github.com/erikrose/blessings) with more intuitive interfaces (but lack of some controls, especially on getting keys).

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
import os
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

or you could try:

```
import subprocess
import platform

def clear():
    subprocess.Popen( "cls" if platform.system() == "Windows" else "clear", shell=True)

clear()
```

Comment: Getting the same problem with both of these. Any other suggestions?

Comment: well, these should work. it might be something else within your code? this might work,         print(“\033[H\033[J”)